# Variable Value Substitution

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to read a config file and get the value of the parameter using the following code.

```
#!/bin/bash

app=ag
echo $app

#works if actual value of $app is used in quotes
processes=$(awk -F ' *= *' '$1=="ag"{print $2}' conf.cfg)

#doesn't work if trying to derive from variable
processes=$(awk -F ' *= *' '$1=="$(echo $app)"{print $2}' conf.cfg)
processes=$(awk -F ' *= *' '$1==\""$app"\"{print $2}' conf.cfg)
```

How to use variable value in the `awk` processing above?

Comment: Stop surrounding your awk expression with single-quote but try with double-quote instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand the desired result you should use such construction:

```
processes=$(awk -v APP="${app}" -F ' *= *' '$1 ~ APP {print $2}' conf.cfg)
-v - argument assignment
```

I'm not really sure but I didn't find in my knowledge base samples of awk using global variable. May be there is any other more elegant samples.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me.